# Testing JasperReports patch in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, patch

I'd like to test a patch I made to JasperReports - how do I point iReport to use the patched JAR? Do I have to get the iReport source, put in the patched JAR and recompile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll need to recompile. The jasperreports JARs are inside `[install_dir]\ireport\modules\ext`. I imagine that replacing the JAR there will do the trick.